# custom ul li, align bullet to center (as text)?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a custum bullet list (ul li)

I have this:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;  
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
    background-image: url(img/bullet.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 5px; 
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

Result text:

```
o            some text
o         some other text
o    and again some other text
```

The main text is centered, and I want the bullets to align to center too (right next to left of text)
Text-align didn't help

How to do this?

Comment: You should consider using a `span` for the icon itself

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't generate the output you have alone. What's centering the text?

Comment: remove the background-position attribute from UL LI and see what you get.

Comment: @j08691 I use text-align: center; on the text

Comment: @VikingBlooded removing background-position did nothing.. well it made the bullets align more to the top of the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:before` pseudo-element to render the bullet with a white bullet unicode char (`\25e6`), like this:

```
ul li:before {        
  content:'\25e6';
  margin-right:5px;    
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:1.5em;
  line-height:0;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gyQ2W/1/)

Comment: Yes, that works :) But I need bigger bullets.. I think thats why I had to make a custom bullet. Or can that be done with your solution?

Comment: @mowgli you can increase the `font-size` from `1.5em` to such as `2em`. With this kind of technique, you can even customize the bullets much more, see this demo of mine http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/Hj8Nn/.

Comment: Is it safe to use utf-8 characters in css/html like content:'●'; ?

Comment: And.. it's not perfectly middle.. hmm, how to align it perfectly

Comment: @mowgli use the char directly requires your html file to set charset to `utf-8` in header.

Comment: @mowgli it's middle for me, what is the value you set for the `font-size`?

Comment: I have no font-size on my document.. I have tried setting it on this li element, various sizes and no size. No change... it's aligned to somewhere between middle and bottom

Comment: Same in chrome, safari, firefox

Comment: @mowgli I mean setting the `font-size` for the `:before` element, it should have the `font-size` set (by `em`) to be bigger than the text beside.

Comment: Yes. That's what I have tried.. setting 1em.. 1.5em.. 4em.. and no size setting at all. Same result: Changes size but is aligned to lower half/middle

Comment: @mowgli I would like to see how much it is offset via some screen shot, could you make some one? because as I see on my side it's almost middle. In the demo, the first 2 lines are middle while the last line is just a little (very little) offset to the top half (or upper half) not lower half as you said.

Comment: @mowgli there is a high chance that you use a wrong unicode character, if you want to use the black bullet, try this code `\2022` (`•`) instead. If you mean the black bullet you posted in the comment above, its code is `\25cf`.

Comment: The first one looks better, but only if very small.. its as if the "middle" is the bullet's top, not it's center

Comment: @mowgli I've tried finding out what's wrong here, in fact when the first letter (in each line) is lower-case, you can feel like it's really middle. But when the first letter is upper-case and the bullet is fairly large, you feel like it's offset to the bottom. It's how `vertical-align:middle` works, if you want to offset it to the top a little, you can set `postion:relative` and `top:-0.02em` like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/gyQ2W/2/ , you can try removing the `top:-0.02em` to see the visual effect of offsetting downwards.

Comment: Looks decent. I wonder if it's x-browser. But so far so good, thanks

Comment: And you're right.. if I compare the middle of a default bullet to the middle of ALL the text in the line, its actually middle ;)

Comment: @mowgli you can be sure that `position:relative` and `top` property are the most basic features of CSS, so of course it runs OK on all browers :)

Comment: I read that "vertical-align: middle" itself often varies on some browsers, especially with bullets.. maybe its not the case anymore. Now I'm just gonna set a -0.2em and leave it at that. Thanks